# Passing input text value with file upload in primefaces

Tags: jsf, input, file-upload, primefaces, jsf-2

I have the requirement that I have to pass the value of inputText to backing bean which will contain the version of the file along with the file upload.
I have been trying to achieve it using remote command but not working.

Below is my code:

```
 <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="uploadForm">
                        <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />
                        <p:outputLabel for="vers" value="File Version:" />
                        <p:inputText id="vers" name="vers"
                            value="#{remoteDeployment.uploadedVersion}" placeholder="1.x.x.x"
                            maxlength="17" required="true"
                            requiredMessage="Version is required." />
                        <p:separator />
                        <p:fileUpload onstart="submitVersion()"
                            fileUploadListener="#{remoteDeployment.upload}" update="messages" >
                            <f:attribute name="terminalSettings" value="#{as}" />
                        </p:fileUpload>


                        <p:remoteCommand name="submitVersion" process="@this vers" />

                    </h:form>
```

String in backing bean for input text :

```
@ViewScoped
    private String uploadedVersion;
    public String getUploadedVersion() {
        return uploadedVersion;
    }

    public void setUploadedVersion(String uploadedVersion) {
        this.uploade
```

please help and also let me know if there is any other way of doing it.

Thanks

Comment: change the onstart with onclick andd tell me if there's anything différente

Comment: @YagamiLight didn't work.

Comment: did you try the classic file upload method from the primefaces web site ?!?

Comment: @YagamiLight yes its from the website.

Comment: i will post the fileupload that worked for me and tell me if there's a difference OK ?!?

Comment: @YagamiLight yeah sure ... but it should be passing the value of input text to backing bean also ?

Comment: can you tell why you couldn't use command button instead of remote command?

Comment: @SajithHerath I have to save the file when the file is uploaded. Command button will be used for some other purpose.

Comment: I think you can achieve what you want with a command button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="uploadForm">
    <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true"/>
    <p:outputLabel for="vers" value="File Version:"/>
    <p:inputText id="vers" name="vers"
                 value="#{remoteDeployment.uploadedVersion}" placeholder="1.x.x.x"
                 maxlength="17" required="true"
                 requiredMessage="Version is required."/>
    <p:separator/>
    <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{remoteDeployment.upload}" update="messages">
        <f:attribute name="terminalSettings" value="#{as}" oncomplete="$('#uploadForm').submit()"/>
    </p:fileUpload>

</h:form>
```

Comment: its not the answer to my question but its one way of doing it.I will accept it as answer for now.

Comment: @Talib I updated answer for the your requirement without commandbutton. You can use PF commands to submit the form in fileupload oncomplete

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem easily
Is's sufficient to put <p:ajax /> between textinput tags

```
    <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="uploadForm">
                    <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />
                    <p:outputLabel for="vers" value="File Version:" />
                    <p:inputText id="vers" name="vers"
                        value="#{remoteDeployment.uploadedVersion}" 
               placeholder="1.x.x.x"  maxlength="17" required="true"  requiredMessage="Version is required.">    
 <p:ajax />
    </p:inputtext>
                    <p:separator />
                    <p:fileUpload onstart="submitVersion()"
                        fileUploadListener="#{remoteDeployment.upload}" update="messages" >          
                    </p:fileUpload>
                </h:form>
```